# Highcharts & range area high

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have three HighCharts series. I have one serie with name Ignition with values 1 and 0 - [1395283486000, 1], [1395283486000, 1], [1395283486000, 1], [1395283486000, 0].

I want to make bar or somethink other with 100% height - start from 1 and ends with 0 (100% height whatever series is shown on the chart). For example I looks at fuel serie and I want to give a duration of the ignition with bar from 1 to 0.

Look the source code at: http://zodiite.net/test/  and I hope to tell me how to do this.

I want to look like this: http://zodiite.net/test/graphic.png

Comment: Could you attach any mockup how it should look like?

Comment: http://zodiite.net/test/graphic.png

Comment: You can use plotBands http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.plotBands

Comment: This is not enought because I will use plotBands with from and to but It's only for the vertical but I need for horizontal too. Like the mockup

Comment: You can also use for horizotnal but for yAxis. see the option http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.plotBands